# what's the standard way of communicating what color highlighting means?

Tags: user-interface, frontend

I have a table UI where I have to highlight records breached some company SLO, I am not a front-end engineer and I would like to know what's the standard way(s) to communicate the meaning of highlighting colors to the users of this interface?